# working of sort function in c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I am reading my friends code and came across this part `sort(c + 1, c + n + 1, compare);`
where c is an object for class customer defined as

```
class customer {
public:
int si;
int fi;
int pi;
};
```

and writes a function

```
bool compare(customer a, customer b)
{
    if (a.pi < b.pi) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (a.pi > b.pi) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        return a.fi < b.fi;
    }
}
```

can anyone please explain how the sort function works and how is this compare function gets linked with sort function.

Comment: Should use reference and `const` for the compare. i.e. `bool compare(const customer &a, const customer 7b);`

Comment: Instead, you should explain what you don't understand about it.

Comment: @EdHeal I don't think it is must. Because it is working even if I pass them directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::sort [is defined](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) as:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
  void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp);
// Sorts the elements in the range [first,last) into ascending order.
// The elements are compared using operator< for the first version, and comp for the second.
```

In your case, I assume `c` refers to an entry in a collection of customers, since the call to

```
sort(c + 1, c + n + 1, compare);
```

will sort the `n` customers that immediately follow `c` in the collection, using `compare` to determine the order.

std::sort will perform the sorting for you, using some [sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) (probably quicksort in most implementations). In order to do that, it needs to be able to compare two elements. This is where the `compare` function comes into play:

```
Binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments,
and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates
whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go before
the second in the specific strict weak ordering it defines.
```

In your case, the `compare` function will sort customers in ascending order of `pi`, and ascending order of `fi` (within equal `pi`).

Answer (score 2):

In C++ std::sort is a standard library function and is typically implemented using quick sort. It is implemented as a template function and this overload is templated on the type of the comparator, the function then takes a callable object as it's third parameter and uses this as the comparison function for the sort. Typically this means the compiler will be able to inline the comparison function into the template instantiation of the sort function template, although it may end up being a function call.